# Is there any way to filter out the information from AWS Sqs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Is there any way to filter out the information(based on some condition) from AWS Sqs before fetching into an application.

Comment: Filter out messages? No, you can't do this. However, in SNS you can do some message filtering if you can use sns.

Comment: Actually i want to perform some conditions on sqs and based on that retrieve messages in my application that satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to selectively retrieve messages from an Amazon SQS queue.

Amazon SQS does support **Message Attributes**, where you can add meta-data to a message (eg Customer ID), but they cannot be used to filter which messages will be received.

If you only want to retrieve particular subsets of messages, then **use multiple queues**.

Comment: Is there any alternative other than using multiple queues?

Comment: As per above, it is not possible to selectively retrieve messages from an Amazon SQS queue.

Comment: Can i use lamda function or some other aws service to filter out messages from sqs?

Comment: As per above, it is not possible to selectively retrieve or filter messages from an Amazon SQS queue.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter messages on the SNS subscription, based on message attributes. This way SQS wouldn't receive the messages from SNS which don't match with the JSON attribute values.

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/filter-messages-published-to-topics/